# Golang Dynamically Unmarshalling JSON

Tags: json, go, refactoring

Is it possible in Go, given the below function, to unmarshall `jsonString` without knowing the type of `c` at runtime?

```
func findChargedItems(fs financialService, conditions []string) ([]*models.ChargedItem, error) {
    var jsonResult []string

    f := getChargedItemsQuery(conditions)
    q, _, _ := f.ToSql()

    err := fs.db.Select(&jsonResult, q)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    jsonString := fmt.Sprintf("[%v]", strings.Join(jsonResult, ","))
    c := make([]*models.ChargedItem, 0)
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &c)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return c, nil
}
```

The problem is that I have tons of models that need to do this exact process and I'm repeating myself in order to achieve this. I would like to just have a "generic" function `findEntities` that operates agnostic of `ChargedItem` and `getChargedItemsQuery`. I realize I can just pass a function in for `getChargeditemsQuery` so that takes care of the that problem, but I am having issues with `json.Unmarshal`, for instance, when I try to use an interface, the json fields do not map correctly. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do without affecting the data models?

Comment: You can do it the same way `json.Unmarshal` does it, by passing in the typed value you want to unmarshal into. It's unclear if that would work in your use case.

Comment: you should refactor so that the selector can decode for you directly. So you could write `err := fs.db.Select(&c, q)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it's probably not a good idea. At any rate, this should do what you are wanting:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   // do what youre trying to do
   var (
      a = []byte("[10, 11]")
      b []interface{}
   )
   json.Unmarshal(a, &b)
   // then fix it later
   c := make([]float64, len(b))
   for n := range c {
      c[n] = b[n].(float64)
   }
   fmt.Println(c)
}
```

Comment: If that's not a good idea, what would you say is a more idiomatic way of achieving the same result without having to repeat so much code?

Comment: @SirBeastalot you havent really given enough information in the question for me to be able to answer that